# help in using HttpWebResponse c#

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I need your help in finding better way in downloading a url using HttpWebResponse

I used next code

```
    HttpWebResponse myboot = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.wwenews.us/m1.php?id=441229").GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    StreamReader myboot_content = new StreamReader(myboot.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256"));
    string temp_data = myboot_content.ReadToEnd();
```

**but a problem says**

```
The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF
```

appears to me when trying parsing ***http://www.wwenews.us/m1.php?id=441229***

please help me to download string of this site

note: **test your solution code before present it as I had tested several solutions and no one solve the problem**

Comment: I tried your code. Not repro! Page is downloaded.

Comment: Post full error message including stack trace please.

Comment: You can also use the HttpClient to "download" the page. It will be easier to use than the HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse but lacks a little functionality

Comment: Do you happen to have Skype installed on the machine where you perform your tests? It can explain your problem as it's using the same port as the web server.

Comment: any way to change the port if it true that skype use the same port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project and add the following method.

```
public static bool SetUnsafeHeaderParsing()
    {
        Assembly oAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection));
        if (oAssembly != null)
        {
            Type oAssemblyType = oAssembly.GetType("System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal");
            if (oAssemblyType != null)
            {

                object oInstance = oAssemblyType.InvokeMember("Section",
                  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { });

                if (oInstance != null)
                {
                    FieldInfo objFeild = oAssemblyType.GetField("useUnsafeHeaderParsing", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (objFeild != null)
                    {
                        objFeild.SetValue(oInstance, true);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Call the method `SetUnsafeHeaderParsing()` before you use the `HttpWebRequest.Create` method call.

Its actually a problem with the server. The server is not following the HTTP specifications. However your .NET client by default would adhere to the specs and flags it as a potential problem.

Comment: @HCL When I started writing the answer your answer was a one liner. The snippet I posted is the one that I had been using with my projects. If you feel offended by it, I am sorry about that.. editing it.

Comment: Thanks شكراً .. HCL and Danish Khan

Comment: not sure what happened here.. the user [HCL][1] had posted a similar solution few minutes before me and was not happy with my response. Hence, I had striked out my solution. But, a few minutes later, I see his reply and all his comments deleted. :$ 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/users/340628/hcl

Comment: @Danish Khan: No problem, I have deleted my post, you have the accept. It makes no sense to have two times the same code in SO :)

Comment: Would be better not to use reflection to set non-public properties on an implementation that is not guaranteed to remain constant. Better to set <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true"/> in the app.config/web.config

Comment: Yeah, that could be done as well.. however, this approach would work if the config files are not available.. like if this code is a part of some library.. Of course, the developer should implement it in a way that its used only when required and not let it stay on by default...

Answer (score 0):

Skype installed on the same machine as the web server can cause such problems, as it's using the same port (80) by default.

To change that port look here:
http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=31024